# laravel multidimensional array

Tags: collections, laravel-5

I have a notifications table in database and also have a users table.In notifications table I have user_id,notific_user_id,post_id.I can print_r $user variable which is in Controller but can to access the $user->first_name.

This is the Controller:

```php
public function test()
{
    $result=Notifications::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
    echo '<pre>';


    foreach ($result as $result){
        $user=User::where('id',$result->notific_user_id)->first()->get();
        print_r($user);
    }
}
```

And this is some of the output

```
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
 (
[items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => App\User Object
            (
                [connection:protected] => 
                [table:protected] => 
                [primaryKey:protected] => id
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 100000000
                        [created_at] => 2016-04-28 19:25:01
                        [updated_at] => 2016-05-10 05:03:22
                        [user_name] => 1
                        [first_name] => Tuhin
                        [last_name] => Hossain
                        [nick_name] => 
                        [email] => tuhinhossain47@gmail.com
                        [password] => $2y$10$XtUWwJwVe2qf86CSUN6AkOkQlCWYq8/b3TrvBt2xuMlh4wTzRgxbG
                        [date_of_birth] => 2016-04-30
                        [gender] => 1
                        [remember_token] => a1U4V4rgJogw3hzXE9jJ8kHqtVrR5FkrMlvLEaRsC6qtmgX3LAbB3MkrZAgz
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 100000000
                        [created_at] => 2016-04-28 19:25:01
                        [updated_at] => 2016-05-10 05:03:22
                        [user_name] => 1
                        [first_name] => Tuhin
                        [last_name] => Hossain
                        [nick_name] => 
                        [email] => tuhinhossain47@gmail.com
                        [password] => $2y$10$XtUWwJwVe2qf86CSUN6AkOkQlCWYq8/b3TrvBt2xuMlh4wTzRgxbG
                        [date_of_birth] => 2016-04-30
                        [gender] => 1
                        [remember_token] => a1U4V4rgJogw3hzXE9jJ8kHqtVrR5FkrMlvLEaRsC6qtmgX3LAbB3MkrZAgz
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )
```

Now how can I access the first_name, last_name etc?
I tried `print_r($user->first_name);` but it did not work. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a collection (list of objects), since you use the `->get()` method for your Eloquent query builder

simply remove the ->get() and you will get the first object matching the query

Your code should look like this:

```
$user=User::where('id',$result->notific_user_id)->first();
```